# How can I get a TDBLookupComboBox to show what you are typing?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have a `TDBLookupComboBox` on my form.

When I put my cursor in it and type, the selection jumps a head to what I've typed (or as close as it can).

However I don't get any indication of what I've typed in the field.

`TDBComboBox` performs similarly to `TDBLookupComboBox` however, when I type in the field, the characters I type appear in regular text, and the 'completion' of the selection appears in inverse/selected following the regular text.

Is there a way I can make `TDBLookupComboBox` perform like `TDBComboBox` in this respect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't make TDBLookupComboBox act like a TDBComboBox (without a bit of hacking).

The problem is that TDBLookupComboBox is used to lookup an index-field (normally a number) from another table. The chosen index is set in the destination-field. When you make TDBLookupComboBox "editable" (like TDBComboBox), you could type in anything, **even values not in the source-table**. And that shouldn't happen (by design). What index-value would you set in that case in the destination field?

You have several options.
You could "hack" TDBLookupComboBox to override the paint procedure to overwrite the selected text with the not selected (already typed) text. It's not easy. Especially if you want to maintain the functionality correctly. But here is some code where I think I've come close to what you want. Although when typing something that's not in the lookup-dataset it doesn't go any further. (It also doesn't account for right aligned text etc.):

```
type
  TDBLookupComboBox = class(DBCtrls.TDBLookupComboBox)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure KeyPress(var Key: Char); override;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    DBLookupComboBox1: TDBLookupComboBox;
//.....

procedure TDBLookupComboBox.Paint;
var
  TextPart: String;
begin
  inherited;
  Canvas.Font := Font;
  Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
  // keeps case like the field is drawn
  TextPart := Copy(Text, 1, Length(SearchText));
  Canvas.TextOut(2, 2, TextPart);
end;

procedure TDBLookupComboBox.KeyPress(var Key: Char);
begin
  inherited;
  // we need this because paint is already called
  // we need to call it again to overwrite the text
  invalidate;
end;
```

It overrides the DBLookupComboBox at the top of your form. You don't have to compile this into a new component. You can just paste it into your form with the DBLookupComboBox. We need to call Paint again after keypress (with invalidate) because paint is already called before coming to that routine.

Another option is to use the TDBComboBox. You can fill the pulldown-items in OnEnter.

```
procedure TForm1.DBComboBox1Enter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBComboBox1.Items.Clear;
  IBQuery1.First;
  while not IBQuery1.EOF do
  begin
    DBComboBox1.Items.Add(IBQuery1.FieldByName('TESTFIELD').DisplayText);
    IBQuery1.Next;
  end;
end;
```

If that's too slow (when entering the combobox) you could also fill the items at opening of the dataset.

Another few options from Jedi-library:

JvDBLookupCombo1
Has a pulldown directly when typing. The original typed text stays in the box.

TJvDBSearchComboBox
Also does what you want but is not connected to a destination datasource. You'll need to set the desired field yourself on OnExit.